# MVC 3 - Redirect based on country?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ip-geolocation

If I had several country sites, e.g. .co.uk, .de, .fr etc... how would be best to go about redirecting based on IP information (or other sources if recommended)? Using MVC 3 and not browsers that don't support HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Maxmind's free GeoIP database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecountry) to figure out what country the client is in. 
They have a C# API that should work well with MVC3.

Comment: Future reference - Code example here: http://lukencode.com/2010/05/19/ip-to-geo-location-in-asp-net-mvc/